# How to correctly sort dictionary by its value in Python?

Tags: python

Given the dictionary below, I tried to sort it by the value order `0,1,2,3,4` without any success

```
items = {
            'Customer'          : ['Form', 'Customer is module for recording information.', 0], 
            'Age'               : ['Label', 'This field for input Age of Customer automatically calculated by system against date of birth.', 4], 
            'Salutation'        : ['Label', 'A greeting in words or actions or the words used at the beginning of a letter or speech.', 2], 
            'As a Guarantor'    : ['Label', 'Whether or not a customer is a guarantor to another customer.', 1], 
            'First Name English': ['Label', 'The name that was given to you when you were born and that comes before your family name.', 3]
        }

print "before sort dictionary"
print items

items    = dict(sorted(items.items(),key=lambda (k,v):int(v[2]))) # Sort Dictionary By key/value 'Order'
print "after sort dictionary"
print items
```

After `sorted()`, the dictionary slightly changed but still not correctly, the item after sorted is as this:

```
{
    'Customer'          : ['Form', 'Customer is module for recording information.', 0], 
    'As a Guarantor'    : ['Label', 'Whether or not a customer is a guarantor to another customer.', 1], 
    'Age'               : ['Label', 'This field for input Age of Customer automatically calculated by system against date of birth.', 4], 
    'Salutation'        : ['Label', 'A greeting in words or actions or the words used at the beginning of a letter or speech.', 2], 
    'First Name English': ['Label', 'The name that was given to you when you were born and that comes before your family name.', 3]
}
```

Please kindly help how can sort this dictionary correctly? Thanks

Comment: default `dict` is not ordered in python. Maybe you can look at `orderedDict`.

Comment: Use python 3.7 where dicts are insertion ordered by default or use `orderedDict`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar, Thanks, I know about that fact, and googled around and found something of sorted() method that worthwhile to try. Without knowing why, some value it sorted correctly, but some are not, like this one.

Comment: @JibinMathews currently my python is 2.7, thanks

Comment: Huh? If you know that dicts aren't ordered, then what's your question?

Comment: @Aran-Fey somehow my application needs that, to sort the value of `dict` and I know there must be workaround solution. Thanks

Comment: Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).